# python regex for grabbing specific parts of a line

Tags: python, regex

Want to go through lines in a file and grab certain parts of them.

Lines look like the below 
    "2584\tM108\tK:14%"
    "2585\tM108\tK:14%\tN:10%"

I have written the following expressions but they seem to be failing me...
Firstly I am looking to grab the M10* and the K, and stick them together, taking only the first entry after the M10* (in the above example K).

```
Mutation = re.sub(r'.*\t(.*)\t.*:(.*)%.*', r'\1\2', line)
```

I want Mutation = M108K

Secondly I want to grab the percentage without the % symbol

```
Percentage = re.sub(r'.*\t.*\t.*:(.*)%.*', r'\1', line)
```

I want Percentage = 14

Not very practiced are writing expressions, these don't really work and are inefficient. Any help fixing/optimising them is appreciated.

Comment: I wonder why those who answer seldom upvote the questions they answer. +1 from me, and this is my hint: do not take lazy matching for granted, also take a look at negated character classes. E.g. `[^\t]` matches any symbol but a tab.

Comment: @stribizhev I'm not the upvoter of this question. ya `.*?` would be replaced with `[^\t]` but `.*?` is more understandable..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do all these in a single regex. `.*` is greedy which eats all the characters as much as possible. So you need to make it to do a non-greedy match by adding `?` quantifier next to `*`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "2584\tM108\tK:14%" "2585\tM108\tK:14%\tN:10%"
>>> re.sub(r'^.*?\t(.*?)\t(.*?):(.*?)%.*', r'\1\2 \3', s)
'M108K 14'
```

or

```
>>> mutation,percentage = re.sub(r'^.*?\t(.*?)\t(.*?):(.*?)%.*', r'\1\2 \3', s).split()
>>> mutation
'M108K'
>>> percentage
'14'
```

Comment: Or `mutation, percentage = ...`.